# check if a list of windows services are running and start if not from batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm looking to work on a batch script to check if a number of services are running and if not start them, this is what i have so far to check if a particular service is running:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "service1" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   net start "service1"
  )
```

However, Id like to modify this for loop to check if there are matches for other services such as "service2", "service3", "service4" and "service5" but I don't know how to go about doing this. Is it possible to include these matches in the same For loop?

Thank you

Comment: It isn't as simple as checking for the string `RUNNING`. A service, if started, can have multiple states, and just because the state is not `RUNNING`, does not mean it can be started. The states can be `Stopped`, `Start Pending`, `Stop Pending`, `Running`, `Continue Pending`, `Pause Pending`, `Paused`, and `Unknown`. regardless of that, I'm not sure what happens if you ask a service to start, which is already running, but I'd assume, possibly only an error message, _(which you could send to `NUL`)_. So why not just try starting all of them, and see what happens. Use `sc start`, not `net start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that in one loop with FOR in a batch :

```
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=: " %%H IN ('^(SC QUERY "Service1" ^& SC QUERY "Service2"^) ^| FINDSTR /C:"SERVICE_NAME" /C:"        STATE" ') DO (IF NOT "%%H" == "" (IF "%%I" == "" SET LOCALV_SERV=%%H) & IF NOT "%%I" == "" (IF /I "%%I" NEQ "RUNNING" CALL NET START %%LOCALV_SERV%%))
```

We query multiple services at once by concatenation of multiple SC outputs and then use here FINDSTR ability to search for multiple strings at once to gain the service name plus the service state.

As suggested by @Compo, you should test for many other service states.

For your use case then, the command should be :

```
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=: " %%H IN ('^(SC QUERY "Service1" ^& SC QUERY "Service2" ^& SC QUERY "Service3" ^& SC QUERY "Service4" ^& SC QUERY "Service5"^) ^| FINDSTR /C:"SERVICE_NAME" /C:"        STATE" ') DO (IF NOT "%%H" == "" (IF "%%I" == "" SET LOCALV_SERV=%%H) & IF NOT "%%I" == "" (IF /I "%%I" NEQ "RUNNING" CALL NET START %%LOCALV_SERV%%))
```

Replace Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4, Service5 with the service names you want to target.

As @Compo states that late expansion with CALL might be not appropriate, here is the same script with delayed expansion explicitly enabled :

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=: " %%H IN ('^(SC QUERY "Service1" ^& SC QUERY "Service2"^) ^| FINDSTR /C:"SERVICE_NAME" /C:"        STATE" ') DO (IF NOT "%%H" == "" (IF "%%I" == "" SET LOCALV_SERV=%%H) & IF NOT "%%I" == "" (IF /I "%%I" NEQ "RUNNING" NET START !LOCALV_SERV!))
```

Here's an expansion of my answer, based upon the comments, which enables delayed expansion only where needed within the loop. This version also removes the reliance on `%PATH%`, and `%PATHEXT%`, and improves readability:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "SC=%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe"
Set "FS=%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe"

For /F "Tokens=2-3 Delims=: " %%G In ('
    (%SC% Query "Service1" ^&
     %SC% Query "Service2" ^&
     %SC% Query "Service3" ^&
     %SC% Query "Service4" ^&
     %SC% Query "Service5"^) 2^>NUL
     ^| %FS% /BIC:"SERVICE_NAME:" /C:"        STATE "
') DO (
    If Not "%%G" == "" If "%%H" == "" Set "LOCALV_SERV=%%G"
    If Not "%%H" == "" If /I Not "%%H" == "RUNNING" (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        %SC% Start !LOCALV_SERV!
        EndLocal
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, may I ask what service1 and service2 are so i can work out if i need to add 3,4 and 5 in my usecase? Can I safely assume that I can append my string matches to FINDSTR, sort of like this 'FINDSTR /C:"service1" /C:"service2" ?

Comment: @user1283674 You don't need to alter FINDSTR, it will get the service name by itself from sc output. If you have 5 services to check , just change `SC QUERY "Service1" ^& SC QUERY "Service2"` into `SC QUERY "Service1" ^& SC QUERY "Service2" ^& SC QUERY "Service3" ^& SC QUERY "Service4" ^& SC QUERY "Service5"`

Comment: got it, understood - thank you for your time

Comment: I don't see any benefit in running multiple `sc.exe` commands and a `findstr.exe` all inside another `cmd.exe` instance, then a sequence of `if` commands, and a `net.exe` command, to do what a single `WMIC.exe` command can do. Also why use the different executable `net.exe`, when you've already used `sc.exe`, and that can already `start` a service. Additionally, `net.exe` is not a batch file, if you take a look at the help information for the `Call` command, _(`call /?` in a Command Prompt window)_, you should note that the `Call` is not required, or needed, in this case.

Comment: @Compo CALL is required here in a batch for late expansion. Without it, `net start %LOCALV_SERV%` will be expanded to '' in each loop.  I agree however that `SC START` should be more appropriate than `NET START`, anyway both work and require privileges. WMIC is a very good tool, but is not present on old Windows like XP home or Windows 2000 or limited on Vista/Seven home, etc.  So for IT with old hardware (notebook under XP and the likes), it could be useful to go the full batch way.

Comment: The OP did not state that they were using an Operating System which is over thirteen years old, _(I think Vista came out in 2008)_, unsecure, and out of both support, and extended support, so there is no need to provide answers which cater for such things. I see why you've used `Call` now, _(I wasn't paying attention)_, you're using it as a hack for not having properly implemented delayed expansion, so that you can unnecessarily provide your answer as a single line.

Comment: @Compo OP ask for *"Is it possible to include these matches in the same For loop?"* in the question. And a way to achieve that with a batch may be useful for others dealing with old hardwares. CALL usage is here to have a batch command which doesn't require delayed expansion explicitly enabled.

Comment: I'm aware of what the OP asked, but their decision on doing so was not based upon efficiency, or whether it was the most appropriate methodology, hence my answer. Using `call` is a hack, and there are some potential issues in doing it. You're using a batch file, so there's no need to put everything on one line, just use parentheses, and enable delayed expansion within that `do` portion, or as it's not very likely that services will not include exclamtion points, just enable delayed expansion at the start, and use `!LOCALV_SERV!` instead.

Comment: @Compo I've edited the answer to add the version with explicitly enabled delayed expansion. Does it suit your point ?

Comment: Yes Zilog80, _I hope you don't mind, but I've added an additional example, delaying expansion only where needed, in the loop, to your answer. I've also upvoted it, because whilst it is less efficient, it is technically a direct answer to the specifcally posed question_.

Comment: @Compo, np, perfect script for real operations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative you may not have considered, *(which ignores the advice in my earlier comment)*, it can be run directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), or from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Service Where "Name='Service1' Or Name='Service2' Or Name='Service3' Or Name='Service4 Or Name='Service5 And Started='TRUE' And State !='Running'" Call StartService >NUL 2>&1
```

*You'll need to decide for yourself whether the `Started='TRUE'` part is required, but I'd advise that you certainly leave it in, to begin with.*

Comment: I'll give this a go and see if i'll need to adjust the "started" flag accordingly, thank you